# Ajax call to a local Phantom.js server from local js script

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, extjs, phantomjs

I have set up an Apache server running locally that hosts my web application (written in ExtJs). I have also a secon local server made with phantom.js and listening on port 8080 :

```
var server, service;

server = require('webserver').create();

service = server.listen(8080, function (request, response) {
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.write('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');
    response.close();
});
```

Now I'd like to do an Ajax request from my application to the phantom server :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
        console.log('RESPONSE: ', response);
    },
    filure: function(response){
        console.log('failure: ', response);
    }
});
```

But when running this script I'm getting :

`"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8080/?_dc=1336648497292"` in the console. Does this operation violate the same origin policy ? Or is it something else ? Going to localhost:8080 shows the proper response, so the server is running properly.

Comment: A different port would be a different domain from an origin standpoint.

Comment: *Does this operation violate the same origin policy?* Yes *Or is it something else?* Also yes. The server is reporting a 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: ok can the 'Bad Request' error come from cross domain problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your html is also on localhost:8080? If not (different port => different host) then you have the cross domain ajax problem.

Comment: damn, thought so :/ Nope, html is on port 80.

Comment: try if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 0):

Ajax doesn't work on File protocals!! It only works on HTTP or HTTP . I have found a course on udemy,mentors says ajax wont works on file:d://(path) protocals. So he shifted his files to web server and then he explained his topic on ajax.

hope this helps!